# CBC with AES : Encrypting in Perl and Decrypting in Java

Tags: java, perl, aes, cbc-mode

I am encrypting a file in perl and want to decrypt in java. here is my encryption code:

== Encryption in Perl ==

```
$key = "1234567890123456";
$plain_text = "this is foo";
open ($fh, ">" . $output_file_path) || die ("open ($output_file_path):$!");
my $cipher = Crypt::CBC->new( -key => $key, -cipher => "Crypt::OpenSSL::AES");
$cipher->start("");
print $fh $cipher->crypt($plain_text);
```

And this is the decryption code I am using, but it is not working.

== Decryption in Java ==

```
String key = "1234567890123456";
byte[] encrypted_bytes = READ_DATA_FROM_FILE
SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(key.getBytes());
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, ivSpec);
String plain_text = new String(cipher.doFinal(encrypted_bytes));
```

Can someone help me in this?

Comment: **How** is it not working?

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to be specifying the IV for the perl encryption, and you are not passing `'encrypt'` to the perl `start()` method.  those are the immediate problems that i notice.

this probably isn't the current problem, but will be a problem for working with "non-trivial" text: you are not being careful with your byte <-> char conversions in java (`String.getBytes()` and `new String()`).  you are using methods in java which use the default platform character encoding, which may not be what you want.  it's best to use an explicit charset.